# Does the depth that you plug in an appliance have an effect?

Tags: electrical

Let us assume that we have an outlet that is a bit into the wall(receptacle is set behind cover, so difficult to plug in larger plugs). If an appliance - lets us say a phone charger - were plugged in but only about 5/6 or 7/8 (essentially small difference) the way in, would that affect charging or draw of current? Or would current be consistent as long as the prongs are in contact with the wire?

Comment: It will depend a bit on equipment.  Without knowing how it's built you can't say how much margin was added in the depth of the contacts.  I have to run down to the garage later so if I see a socket laying around maybe I'll smash it.  For something like a powerbar(usually easily disassembled) this would be easy to check nondestructively, but when internal construction is unknown, refer to Transistor's answer.  You can only count on intended safety when devices are used as intended.  Another thing: if a plug is not fully engaged it presents exposed conductors to thin objects ie:pin, paperclip.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a poor electrical contact between the plug and socket contacts.

The result of poor contact is high resistance. 
The result of resistance is voltage drop and heating.

- The voltage drop is given by \$ V = IR \$, where *I* is the current and *R* is the resistance so the more current the lower the voltage delivered to the appliance. Your mobile phone charger takes so little current that it won't matter. A larger load such as a heater or washing machine will suffer a much larger voltage drop and may not work properly.
- The power dissipated in the poor contact is given by \$ P = I^2 R \$, where *I* is the current (amps) and *P* is the power (watts). Notice that the power increases with the *square* of the current so heat build-up becomes significant enough at higher currents that fire becomes a risk.

Comment: Adding on to this, the effect of depth of engagement varies depending on the type of connector. For common north american 120V sockets the contacts are curved, and only touch the plug prongs at one point. This picture shows the internals: http://i.imgur.com/hcBwTFg.jpg?1 

As long as the prongs solidly engage the socket contact area, the engagement depth has little effect. If there is only partial contact then the increased contact resistance will result in excessive heating.